# Is the Inner Circle hit song "Sweat" about rape?

Tags: music

Is the song [Sweat (A La La La La Long)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sweat_%28A_La_La_La_La_Long%29) by Inner Circle really about rape? Does anyone have an interview or something confirming this?

When I was younger it was a hit and we all listened to it without really groking the lyrics...

[YouTube version](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=p0M4J849dmA&feature=related)

Comment: We want to focus our attention on doubtful claims that are widely held or are made by notable people.  Please [provide some references](http://meta.skeptics.stackexchange.com/questions/882/what-are-the-attributes-of-a-good-question/883#883) to places where this claim is being made. Also, this question is asking about the intentions of an individual (or a small group) which is something that can never be answered definitively - especially if they don't mention what the song was about.

Comment: I think the second concern is really minor in this case as the OP is specifically asking if the band said so (which is a true/false question, and answerable). This still leaves notability on the table though.

Comment: Regarding the first concern, the meme is all over the internet :-)

Comment: [Lyrics](http://www.lyricsmode.com/lyrics/i/inner_circle/sweat_a_la_la_la_la_long.html) do not back up that claim IMO in any way. But this is anecdotal.  Which makes this a question of motivation which would be off topic.